# Duplicate http cookie header in nativescript Android

Tags: android, cookies, nativescript

Making http request cookie header gets added multiple times.
only happens in Android. tested same code in iOS and it works fine.

CLI: 2.1.0
Cross-platform modules: 2.1.0
Runtime(s): tns-android : 2.1.1

```
var http = require("http");
...
        return http.request({
            url: url,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
            "Cookie": "Bearer=XSTH4q...Je7",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
            "Connection": "keep-alive"
        },
         content: postData,
        });
```

tns emulate android --geny="g1"

HTTP traffic in charles proxy:

```
GET /api/account/userinfo HTTP/1.1
Cookie: Bearer=XSTH4q...Je7
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0; g1 Build/MRA58K)
Host: xyz.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Cookie: Bearer=XSTH4q...Je7
```

it seems that android code automatically adds the last "Set-Cookie: " response header to next http requests headers ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is documented bug which is already fixed and the fix will be included in the next NativeScript release (v2.2). More information here : https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2413

Comment: Thanks, when is the next release?

Comment: EDIT: it is under review not fixed but you can track its development in the issue link above